# footer display in html website

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2013
I am trying to make a website divided like this
[image: image 1]

this is my Html code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id ="wrapper">
            <div id =" banner">

            </div>
            <div id="navigation">
                
            </div>
            <div id="content">

            </div>
            <div id ="sidebar">

            </div>
            <div id=" footer">
              <p> AlL rights reserved.</p> 
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is th css code

```
body 
{
    font-family:'Calibri',Verdana , sans-serif;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
#wrapper
{
    width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #dedede;
    background-color: #fff;

}
#banner
{
    height:200px;
    border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
    
}
#navigation
{
    height: 60px;
    border: 3px solid #e3e3e3;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#content
{
    float:left;
    width: 750px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    padding : 10px;
    border: 3px solid #e3e3e3;
}
#sidebar
{
    float:right;
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
     border: 3px solid #e3e3e3;
}
#footer
{
    clear:both;
    width:auto;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:20px;

}
```

the problem that it apear like this:
[image: image 2]

can any one help ? I dont know where is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/m6PG3/1/)

Nice and simple

Add `overflow:hidden;` to `#wrapper`, this wil stop your floated elements from extending beyond the underlying parent without forcing its expansion.

**[Update](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/m6PG3/2/):**

If you want to ensure correct flow with your layout, wrap the `content` and `sidebar` elements in another `div` with `overflow:hidden` set (per jsfiddle link above)

Comment: ok i did >> its better but the footer is in the same wrong place

Comment: sorry my english is littele bad ~~ u mean I make a new div
put content and sidebar in?

Comment: @AishaAhmedAhmed no problem :) have a look at the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/m6PG3/2/

Answer (score 1):

It is happen because you have lost layout. Please read about "HasLayout" on the web to avoid this in future

Add please

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    overflow:hidden
}
```

Comment: the wrapper is better now

Comment: Are you tried to read what I wrote??? I see not. You need to wrap your content and sidebar for example by .content-holder and add overflow:hidden on it too